# Prove an inequality about $\arctan 1/(nx)$ for any $x$ and $n$

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence

How to prove this inequality for any $x$ and $n$?

$$
\left|\arctan\frac 1{nx}\right| \leq \frac 1{nx} ;\, 0<x<+{\infty}
$$

Is this bounded? But how that can help me in proving? I mean that I don't know the interval of boundedness..

Please tell me how to prove this inequality?

Comment: Show that $\tan(u)\geqslant u$ for every $u$ in $[0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: Didier, thanks. How to show it? I thought that $$ \tan(u)< u $$

Comment: @Didier, I'm sorry, I was wrong. And then, after showed?

Comment: Once you know that $\tan(u)\geqslant u$ for every $u$ in $[0,\pi/2)$, deduce from this an inequality between $\arctan(v)$ and $v$, valid for every $v\geqslant0$.

Comment: See also this question: [Why $x<\tan{x}$ while $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let us look at $\arctan t$, say for $t \ge 0$. We would like to show that  $\arctan t\le t$.

The standard approach is to let $f(t)=t-\arctan t$, and note that 
$$f'(t)=1-\frac{1}{1+t^2} \ge 0.$$