# Geometrical interpretation of tan(x) > x

Tags: trigonometry

Is there a geometrical interpretation for $tan(x) > x$ when $x \in (0, \frac{\pi}{2})$ in the unit circle? I can't picture it since $x$ is the angle (although it makes sense when you graph the two functions).

Comment: Check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2

Comment: @Macavity hadn't seen this; thanks!