# Proof $\;\frac{\sin x}{x} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}1$

Tags: calculus

I read this proof https://www.dropbox.com/s/wo2dvhk2hqa6sk1/Screenshot%202014-05-03%2016.22.45.png and I wonder: how do we know that

$$x < \tan x?$$

also, we assume that $x>0$, is this because we take the right hand limit?

Comment: There are many ways of doing so. Do you know Taylor expansion?

Comment: yes, but can't use it in the proof

Comment: Does "bevis" = "proof"?

Comment: @user88595 Yes, it does. The linked page is in Swedish. Also, "Sats" = "Proposition", more or less.

Comment: Please translate and rewrite the proof in the post if you want most people to be able to answer you.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=plot+x%2Ctan(x)&rlz=1C1JRYI_enIN487IN487&oq=plot+x%2Ctan(x)&aqs=chrome..69i57.8842j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=plot+tan(x)%2Cx

Comment: In the link by Henrik, in the answer by David, it is completely clear from the geometrical figure why $\;\sin x<\tan x\;$ .

Comment: @Awesome A drawing of a graph is _never_ a full proof. It can accompany and greatly help a proof, true, but it is not enough. If you rely too helvily on drawings, then you open up to intuition taking over where reasoning should be used, and you end up making mistakes, like in [this proof](http://www.mathematik.com/Isoscele/) that all triangles are isosceles.

Comment: @Arthur It's just meant to be a visual representation.

Comment: The drawing in this case is so basic that it *almost* is a proof by itself. Anyway, doing a little trigonometry here and there the inequality follows at once.

Comment: To give a proof, the definition of $\sin$ is needed.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

$$x=\frac{\text{arc}}{\text{radius}}$$

$$\sin{x}=\frac{\text{perpendicular}}{\text{radius}}$$

As $x\to 0,\text{arc}\to \text{perpendicular}$

Hence, $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}= 0$

Now you can find derivatives of trigonometric functions and prove that derivative of $\tan x =\sec^2 x$

And then analyse the function $\tan x-x$ and see that it is non negative in $[0,\pi/2)$ and hence $x<\tan x$

Now you can proceed in your proof.

**PS**: I have a strange feeling that you might not want to go through the proof now.

Comment: Well, one wants to prove that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$ in that way in order to compute the derivative of the sine function. So the derivative of the tangent is not available.

Comment: @egreg Edited... :P

Comment: how come that "strange feeling" of yours?