# Proving $x\leq \tan(x)$

Tags: calculus, geometric-inequalities

How can i prove that $x\leq \tan(x)$ for any $x$ in $[0,\frac{\pi}{2})?$

Comment: is it $x \leq \tan(x)$ or $x \geq \tan(x)$?

Comment: In the title you have $x \geq \tan(x)$ and in the question $x\leq \tan(x)$, which is it?

Comment: @M.Van i corrected it

Comment: @user315918 Drop the square parentheses on the right side: tangent isn't defined there.

Answer (score 6):

Define

$$f(x):=x-\tan x\implies f'(x)=1-\frac1{\cos^2x}=\frac{\cos^2x-1}{\cos^2x}\le0\implies f(x)$$

monotonic decreasing, and since $\;f(0)=0\;$, we get for $\;x\in[0,\pi/2)\;$ that

$$x-\tan x=f(x)\le f(0)=0\implies x\le \tan x$$

Comment: +1 you typed exactly the same thing but faster than me dude :P

Answer (score 3):

Proving this using calculus is likely a bit circular in logic. That's because $x < \tan x$ for $0<x<\pi/2$ is usually proved first, using geometry, before any derivatives of trig functions have been established. The inequality $x < \tan x$  is then used to obtain $(\sin x)/ x \to 1,$ which leads to the derivatives of all the trig functions.

The geometry argument goes like this: The sector of the unit circle determined by the arc $x$ has area $x/2.$ That sector has area smaller than the triangle with vertices $(0,0), (1,0), (1,\tan x);$ the picture makes that clear. The area of that triangle is $(1/2)\cdot 1 \cdot \tan x.$ Thus $x/2 < (\tan x) /2,$ which gives $x < \tan x$ as desired.

Comment: +` This is the way I would have presented an answer.

Comment: I said the same thing with an illustration [2 days ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1786480/316404).

Comment: After the many editions of the question it could be that it is "preferable" (for whom?) a geometric proof of the inequality, which by the way is almost trivial. Yet the first versions of the question said "How can I prove... **with derivation, please?**"

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that "it is circular to prove this inequality via calculus". +1

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Let $x \in [0,\frac\pi2)$. Then, one has
$$
(x)'=1\leq 1+\tan^2 x=(\tan x)'
$$ and one may conclude with $0\leq \tan 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Using Taylor's theorem for $x\in[0,\pi/2)$ write $\tan(x)=x+(sec\zeta\tan\zeta)\frac{x^2}{2}$ where $\zeta$ is some  number between $0$ and $x$. Since $(sec\zeta\tan\zeta)\geq 0$ we have that $\tan(x)\geq x.$

Answer (score 1):

You could show, equivalently, that $\arctan(y)\le y$ for $y\ge 0$. For this the familiar fact
$$
\arctan(y) = \int_0^y {1\over 1+x^2}\,dx,\qquad y\ge 0
$$
will be useful.

Answer (score -2):

You can't prove it because it is false:$$
\frac{3\pi}{4} > \tan\left( \frac{3\pi}{4} \right)=-1
$$
And in case you want the $\leq$ sign as in the title,
$$
\frac{\pi}{4} < \tan\left( \frac{3\pi}{4} \right)=1
$$

Comment: 3π/4  is greater than π/2…

Comment: $\frac{3 \pi}{4}> \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: He posted it before it was edited by OP

Comment: Yes, when I posted this, no range was specified in the question.