# Using the Squeeze Theorem to Evaluate $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2} {\sin^2(t)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know from L'Hopital's Rule that  $$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2} {\sin^2(t)}=1$$

But I'm also trying to verify this using the Squeeze Theorem.

My first thought is to use the upper and lower bounds of possible outputs (range) of $\sin^2(t)$ as the functions which $\sin^2(t)$ would be between:

$$ 0 \leq \sin^2(t) \leq 1 $$

We want the function in the middle of the inequality to resemble the function we are taking the limit of, so dividing the whole inequality by $t^2$

$$0 \leq \frac{\sin^2(t)}{t^2} \leq \frac{1}{t^2}$$

Then taking the reciprocal of each term

$$0 \geq \frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)} \geq t^2$$

Now taking the limit of each term of the inequality as $t \to 0$

$$\lim_{t \to 0} 0 \geq \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)} \geq \lim_{t \to 0} t^2$$

$$ 0 \geq \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)} \geq 0$$

Thus, by the Squeeze Theorem

$$\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)} = 0$$

But I know this is incorrect and the limit should evaluate to $1$ just like the answer I got using L'Hopital's Rule. (And this can also be verified looking at the graph of  $\frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)}$ as $t \to 0$).

I'm not sure what step I did incorrectly or perhaps the functions I initially chose as the boundaries are incorrect.

So my questions are how would I evaluate this using the Squeeze Theorem and what part of my thought process is wrong?

Comment: You took the reciprocal of $0$ and got $0$!

Comment: You made a mistake when you took the reciprocal of each term.

Comment: @copper.hat Ah I see, so you mean I have $ 0 = \frac {0}{1}$ and taking its reciprocal I essentially got division by $0$ which is  $\frac{1}{0}$

Comment: Who says you can use the squeeze theorem here?

Comment: @ChrisCuster Could you elaborate your comments in an answer.

Comment: @ChrisCuster I wanted to see if it's possible. I did not think it wasn't possible to use the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: You probably can, come to think of it, since $\sin t\sim t$ for small $t$.

Comment: The issue with using the squeeze theorem is finding suitable bounds. Without resorting to derivatives, nothing obvious leaps out at me.

Comment: FYI:  Knowing $\displaystyle{\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}}$ is equivalent to knowing the derivative of $\sin x$ at $x=0$:
$$
1=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x-\sin 0}{x-0}=\frac{d}{dx}\Bigg|_{x=0}\sin x.
$$
So saying you know the limit from l'Hospital's rule is circular(ish) reasoning (and probably makes every calculus instructor sigh when they see it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the reciprocal of zero isn't zero. Instead, apply the [inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2555688/258202) derived here

$${t-\frac{t^3}{6} \le\sin (t)\le t},$$

which implies

$$ \frac{1}{t^2}\le \frac{1}{\sin^2(t)}\quad\text{and} \quad \frac{1}{\sin^2(t)}\le \frac{1}{\left(t-\frac{t^3}{6}\right)^2}.$$

Therefore

$$1 = \frac{t^2}{t^2}\le \frac{t^2}{\sin^2(t)}\le \frac{t^2}{\left(t-\frac{t^3}{6}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{t^2}{6}\right)^2},$$

and taking the limit as $t\to 0$ gives the upper and lower bound of $1$ needed for the Squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sandwich relation
$$1<\frac{x^{2}}{\sin^{2}x}<\sec^{2}x$$

This easily gives you your desired limit.

Also, this relation can be graphically represented as follows

[image]

That's the sandwich :P

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{t^2}{\sin^2 (t)}=\lim_{t\to 0} \left(\frac{t}{\sin(t)}\right)^2$$
$$=\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)^{-2}=1^{-2}=1.$$
The limit
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\operatorname{sinc}(t)=1$$
Can be verified with the squeeze theorem and has already been discussed at length on this site.