# Limit of sinx/x without taylor series or areas

Tags: trigonometry

I learned at school that the fact that sinx/x goes 1 when x approaches 0 can be proved by comparing areas.

I'm wondering if there is another way to prove it. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: In fact, this can be taken as an axiom, along with the angle addition formulas and even/oddness for $\sin$ and $\cos$. These 5 equations can be used to prove all the other properties (if I remember correctly).

Comment: Needed would be some kind of definitions for $\sin x$, and for $x$ in radians].

Comment: Can you tell us what you dislike about the argument with areas that leads you to seek other proofs? Will you dislike arguments based on arc length comparisons too? It is essential that radian measure is used for sin(x), so in some way that feature should make an appearance. (Using power series seems like overkill.)

Comment: I define sinx and cosx by the unit-circke definition.

Comment: Which "unit-circle" definition?

Comment: I'm just a curious to know if there is other geometrical ways to prove it without areas

Comment: I meant unit-circle definition by https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine

Answer (score 3):

In the diagram, $x$ is the signed length of the arc $DB$, and $\sin x$ is the signed length of the segment $AB$ and $\tan x$ is the signed length of the segment $DC$.

[image: Unit circle]

Either $0<\sin x<x<\tan x$ or $\tan x<x<\sin x<0$.

In either case, $0<\dfrac{\sin x}{x}<1<\dfrac{\tan x}{x}=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{\cos x}$.

Thus $\cos x<\dfrac{\sin x}{x}<1$.

Since $\lim_{x\to0}\cos x=1$ we have $\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}=1$ by the "squeezing" theorem.

**ADDENDUM** Why is $x<\tan x$ when $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Consider the following diagram:

[image: tangent to unit circle]

Construct the tangent to the unit circle at $B$ and mark its intersection with the tangent line $CD$ as $E$. Then $E$ is equidistant from both $D$ and $B$. Construct the circle with center $E$ and radius $BE$. Then we have $x=\text{ arc }DB<BE+ED<DC=\tan x$ [See link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372557/geometric-inequality-involving-a-circular-arc-between-two-vertices-of-a-triangle)

Note that $C$ lies on a tangent line to the smaller circle and is different from the point of tangency, thus it lies outside the smaller circle.

Comment: Why does it follow that CD is longer than BD?

Comment: That's a fair question. Rather than repeat what has already been done, however, there are several [good answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2) already on math.stackexchange.

Comment: Ok, I think my proof is better than the ones given in the link, so I went ahead and added it.

Comment: Why does it follow that $\text{ arc }DB<BE+ED$?

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal Good catch! It certainly cannot be because of $\theta/2<\tan(\theta/2)$. I will see if I can find a better reason.

Comment: @AnshumanAgrawal I have posed this as a math.stackexchange [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4372557/geometric-inequality-involving-acircular-arc-between-two-vertices-of-a-triangle).

Comment: Thanks, I was confused and thought I was missing something obvious

Comment: I also read this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/922970/930811  But couldn't follow the argument for why that holds, in the comments people were saying that's essentially an axiom

Answer (score 0):

There can be another simple intuitive proof for understanding purpose only. Consider a triangle with one angle x at O. And hypotenuse 1. Then the perpendicular gives the magnitude of sin x. Now just imagine the angle x is very small. Then what, the perpendicular would be vary small and the base is nearly the length of hypotenuse. Now to approximate you can consider perpendicular to be a small arc of circle, with radius as the base(=which is same as hypotenuse of unit length), centre at O. Now, using  the definition of angle, we can write: x= (arc length/radius)= sin x. Hence, the limit sin x/x tends to 1 for very small x. Hope this helps you in some way!