# Prove that $\tan(x) \gt x$ for any $x$, $x\in(0,π/2)$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, inequality

I'mm trying to prove that with Lagrange sentence,

$F(x)= \tan(x)$

$G(x)= x$

I was trying to show that for any $x\in(0,π/2)$,
$F'(x)=G'(X)$.

Then according to Lagrange:
$G(X) = C\cdot F(X)$ which means that $F(X)\lt G(X)$ for any $x\in(0,π/2)$.

Comment: For any $x \epsilon (0,\pi/2), tan x\gt x$. Your question is wrong

Comment: I don't think that's correct...

Comment: I believe your statement is wrong. Imagine x is very close to pi/2 ... tan(x) will be very very very very very big while pi/2 will just be pi/2

Comment: @Tojrah Unless he is working in degrees though the range $(0, \pi / 2)$ suggests radians.

Comment: was a mistake tanx>x

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why $x<\tan{x}$ while $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 3):

*Observation:* We are working in the interval $\big(0, \frac{\pi}{2}\big)$.

Let $f(x):=\tan(x)$ and $g(x):=x$

Observe that $$\begin{align*}f'(x)&=\frac{1}{\cos^2(x)}\tag{1}\\&>1=g'(x)\end{align*}$$

Notice, furthermore, that $$f(0)=g(0)$$

Can you finish now?

---

### Addendum

There is also a nice geometric proof

[image]

It follows from the areal comparison of $$\triangle ABC=\frac{\tan(\alpha)}{2}>\text{circular sector }ABD=\frac{\alpha}{2\pi}\cdot(\pi\cdot1^2)$$ Or equivalently $$\frac{\tan(\alpha)}2>\frac\alpha2\iff \tan(\alpha)>\alpha$$

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the fact that, for $x=0, x=tan x$ and$ (tan x)' \ge x' $for all $\pi/2 \ge x\ge0$. Consider $f=tan x-x. f'=sec^2x-1 \ge 0$ for all $\pi/2 \ge x\ge0$ and f(0)=0. So f is increasing, therefore $tan x-x \ge 0.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Do you know the Maclaurin series for tan(x)

and where it converges?

Answer (score 1):

By integration from $0$ to $x$,

$$\sec^20=1,\sec^2x>1\implies \tan x> x.$$