# Prove $\tan^{-1}(2)+\cot^{-1}(3)+\frac{1}{7} > \frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I managed to reduce it to the form
$$\cot(\frac{1}{7})<7$$
But I still don't know how to prove it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why $x<\tan{x}$ while $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x -\tan^{-1}x=\int_0^x \frac{t^2}{1+t^2}dt>0$$

for $x> 0$. Then, let $x=\frac17$ to get $\frac17> \tan^{-1}\frac17=\cot^{-1}7$,
or

$$\cot \frac17< 7$$