# Which is greater , $7\cdot \tan(10^\circ)$ or $10\cdot \tan(7^\circ)$

Tags: analysis

My direction is turning the problem into

$$\frac{\tan(10^\circ)}{10}  \space\space\space\space?\space\space\space\space  \frac{\tan(7^\circ)}{7}$$
then differentiating $f(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{x}$, which is $$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{cos^2(x)}-tan(x)}{x^2}$$

but I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Your title and body seem to be different...

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan its the same...just cross multiply

Comment: Then why the negative sign?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan it is a hyphen, not a minus sign i think.....if it was a minus sign then the answer will be quite obvious....one will be negative and the other positive.

Comment: My bad, I would probably use a colon in cases like that.

Comment: True...colon would be clearer

Comment: @SaketGurjar edited, for future viewers. will keep that in mind next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x)=[x-\sin x \cos x]/[x^2\cos^2 x]$ And $\sin x\cos x\leq \sin x\leq x$ for $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.
So, $f'(x)>0$ in that interval, i e. $f$ is increasing in that interval. Your angles in radians are in that interval, so you can compare the two expressions that you want.

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=\frac{\frac{x}{\cos^2(x)}-\tan(x)}{x^2}=\frac{x-\sin x \cos x}{x^2\cos^2x}=\frac{2x-2 \sin x \cos x}{2x^2\cos^2x}=\frac{2x-\sin 2x}{2x^2\cos^2x}$$

Now to prove that $f'(x)>0$ you need to prove that $2x\gt\sin 2x$ or $\alpha>\sin\alpha$. And this is really trivial. For example, check a few answers given here: [Why $x<\tan{x}$ while $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)