# Proof of $\tan{x}>x$ when $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

I have read [Why $x<\tan{x}$ while $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2)

If I want to get $\tan{x}\gt x$ instead of weaker inequality $\tan{x} \ge x$. Do I need only to show that $\tan{x} \gt x$ when $x\to 0$? Because from @David Mitra 's picture, it is obvious to see $\tan{x}\gt x$ when $x$ is not near $0$.

Since $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\tan{x}}{x}=1 \text{}$$
,for $$\varepsilon=\frac{1}{n} \;\;\text{ where }n\in\Bbb N$$,
we can find $\delta \gt 0 $ s.t. $$\forall x \in (0,0+\delta)$$,
we have $$\frac{\tan{x}}{x}\gt1-\frac{1}{n}$$

Let $n\to \infty$, we get $$\frac{\tan{x}}{x}\gt1$$ So $$\tan{x}\gt x \text{ when }x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Or someone has more analytical proof instead of geometric proof for $x\in(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$,  since I only prove the case $x$ is near the origin. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to suppress the tag "geometry"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a *direct* consequence of the *Mean value theorem*:

For any $x\in \bigl(0,\frac\pi2\bigr)$, we have
$$\frac{\tan x}x=(\tan)'(\xi)\quad(0<\xi<x)\quad =\frac1{\cos^2\xi},$$
and on the interval $\bigl(0,\frac\pi2\bigr)$, $\;0<\cos\xi<1$, so
$$\frac{\tan x}x=\frac1{\cos^2\xi}>1.$$

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!!

Answer (score 5):

Set $$f(x)=\tan(x)-x.$$
One can prove that $f'(x)>0$ on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$, and thus $f$ is strictly increasing on $(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$. Therefore $$f(x)> f(0)=0,$$
for all $x\in (0,\frac{\pi}{2}).$