# How to prove $\sin \frac{1}{k} > \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k^2}$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, contest-math

I am solving a question and I can't get over this step: proving $$\sin \frac{1}{k} > \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k^2}$$
where $k$ is a positive integer.

I tried using induction, but I failed. One of my friends managed to prove it using derivatives but I am searching for a solution which does not involve calculus or series. Proving this would help me solve a convergence problem.

Comment: Hint: Consider $f(x)=\sin x-x+x^2$. What is $f(0)$? Is $f$ monotonic?

Comment: Is $k$ a positive integer?What is the range of $k$?

Comment: Yes, $k$ is a  positive integer.

Comment: @trisct Can you give me any advice regarding how to show its increasing  without using derivatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well if you don't want to use calculus ...

from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98998/why-x-tanx-while-0x-frac-pi2) geometric proof by David Mitra we have $$\sin t\le t\le \tan t$$ Now  $$\tan t/2\ge t/2 $$ $$\sin (t/2)\cos(t/2)\ge \frac{t(1-\sin^2(t/2))}{2}$$ $$\to \sin t\ge t(1-\sin^2 (t/2)\ge t(1-t^2/4)=t-t^3/4$$ Using this result we get $$\sin 1/k\ge \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{4k^3}$$  But $\frac{1}{k}\le 1$ so obviously $$\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{4k^3}\ge \frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}$$ we are done!

Answer (score 5):

We just have to think about:$$f(x)=\sin x-x+x^2,x\in[0,1].\\$$
$$f'(x)=\cos x-1+2x.\\$$Let$\ g(x)=f'(x),$than$$g'(x)=-\sin x+2.\\$$
When $x\in[0,1]$ $$g'(x)>0.\\$$At this point, $f'(x)(=g(x))$  is monotonically increasing.
So$$f'(x)\geq f'(0)=0,$$if and only if $x=0$,the equal sign holds.
Than we can know $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing.
So$$f(x)\geq f(0)=0,$$if and only if $x=0$,the equal sign holds.
Let x=$\frac{1}{k}>0$,come to the conclusion:$$\sin \frac{1}{k}>\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{k^2}.$$

Comment: That's a nice solution, but I am looking for one which doesn't use derivates.

Comment: I have only used derivatives so far for this type of this inequality,and I don't think any other way would be too convenient.

Comment: Proving it for $[\frac{1}{2}, 1]$ is quite easy, but I can't deal with $(0, \frac{1}{2})$